# Combining two queries to get numerator, denominator, and grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two queries. One for the numerator and one for the denominator. How do I combine the two queries so that my result is one table with the numerator, denominator, and grouping?

[image: Query and results]

Example of desired output:

```
Numerator | Denominator | Grouping
----------|-------------|---------
 30       | 51          | 1111
172       | 216         | 2768
```

Comment: Please don't post SQL statements or sample data as screenshots. Post formatted test instead. The SQL isn't even properly readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really have two different aggregates over the same table. For many reasons, performance being one of them, you do not want to break your query down into two parts and then re-join them together. You can accomplish the correct result by using column-level filtering instead of WHERE clause filtering:

```
select [officerID]
    ,sum(case when [ST3ID] != '' then 1 else 0 end) as [Numerator]
    ,count(*) as [Denomimator]
FROM [dbo].[cobanVideos]
WHERE [starting] > '6/1/2015 0:00:00 AM'
AND [starting] < '7/1/2015 0:00:00 AM'
GROUP BY [officerID]
```

By using a CASE statement to filter the data at the column level, you can retrieve both values at the same time.  You can also calculate the percentage value (numerator/denminator) by adding the following as an additional column:

```
select [officerID]
    ,sum(case when [ST3ID] != '' then 1 else 0 end) as [Numerator]
    ,count(*) as [Denomimator]
    ,case when count(*) <> 0 
          then sum(case when [ST3ID] != '' then 1.0 else 0 end) / count(*)
          else 0 
      end as [Pct ST3]
FROM [dbo].[cobanVideos]
WHERE [starting] > '6/1/2015 0:00:00 AM'
AND [starting] < '7/1/2015 0:00:00 AM'
GROUP BY [officerID]
```

SQL Window functions give you a whole other set of tools for working with aggregates at different levels of aggregation, all in one query. If you are interested, I can follow up with an example of how you could calculate the ratio per officerId, for all officers, and also determine the contribution percent of each officer to the overall total, all with a single SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Join:

```
Select numerator.Count, denominator.Count, numerator.officerID  from (SELECT COUNT() as Count, officerID FROM [dbo].[cobanVideos] WHERE starting > '6/1/2015 0:00:00 AM' AND starting < '7/1/2015 0:00:00 AM' AND ST3ID != '' GROUP BY officerID) numerator Join (SELECT COUNT() as Count, officerID FROM [dbo].[cobanVideos] WHERE starting > '6/1/2015 0:00:00 AM' AND starting < '7/1/2015 0:00:00 AM' GROUP BY officerID) denominator On numerator.officerId = denominator.officerId
```

Comment: I tried: `Select * from 
(SELECT COUNT(*), officerID
 FROM [dbo].[cobanVideos] WHERE starting > '6/1/2015 0:00:00 AM' AND starting < '7/1/2015 0:00:00 AM' AND ST3ID != '' GROUP BY officerID) numerator
Join 
(SELECT COUNT(*), officerID
 FROM [dbo].[cobanVideos] WHERE starting > '6/1/2015 0:00:00 AM' AND starting < '7/1/2015 0:00:00 AM' GROUP BY officerID) denominator
On numerator.officerId = denominator.officerId` and got  No column name was specified for column 1 of 'numerator'.
 Msg: 8155, Level: 16, State: 2, Procedure: , Line: 4

Comment: You have to name the columns in the subselect.
Please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

For the result of you want, you must use a Case Statment

Here is the example

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN ST3ID != '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)    [NUMERATOR] ,
COUNT(*)                                        [DENOMINATOR],
officerID                                       [GROUPING]
FROM [dbo].[cobanVideos]
WHERE [starting] > '6/1/2015 0:00:00 AM'
AND [starting] < '7/1/2015 0:00:00 AM'
GROUP BY GROUPINGID
```

For the answer for you question, you must use a Join statment

example:

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(numerator,0)             as [Numerator], 
    ISNULL(Denominator,0)           as [Denominator], 
    ISNULL(a.officerID,b.officerID) as [Grouping] 
FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(*) numerator, officerID ....) AS [TableA]
FULL JOIN 
(SELECT COUNT(*) Denominator, officerID ....) AS [TableB]
ON [TableA].[officerID] = [TableB].[officerID]
```